# Which is better Database design explode or impode? (MariaDB or MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, multi-tenant

I'm developer preparing new version solution of current solution in my company.

Currently, application create database per our clients. For example
db1,db2,db3.....,db100,db101...
And server has 8 thousand of database.

This has benefit of performance of CRUD and backup or rollback database per client. Problem is some noise code on my application source.

I cannot define database config file statically because database created and removed dynamic. All of my code write query using client's number such as below

```
"select * from db"+clientNumber+".table"
```

or create new database connection for every request.

In our new version, I want to manage one database that combined all current database. If I do, some table has tens of million data row. Forasmuch I've never experienced manage tens of million data row table, I cannot judge this is good practice. And how backup and rollback program will developed?

Comment: This is a duplicate of _many_ other questions.  Do _not_ have thousands of table or databases.  Period, full stop.

Comment: 10M rows is much less trouble than 8K databases.

Comment: @RickJames What is example of problem with too many database?

Comment: You have to pick the db; the OS has to find it (since it is implemented as a directory); the table cache needs to be big; etc.